# Make a website responsive only on iPad - how can I NOT output the viewport meta tag for iPhones...?

Tags: html, ios, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a responsive website built on top of Bootstrap. However, I only want it to be responsive on the iPad - the iPhone should show the regular, full site.

In my `<head>` I am using:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

But I only want this to be output if the device is *not* iPhone.

However - this needs to be static HTML - so I can't use PHP or anything server-side. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale: 1, maximum-scale: 1">
```